# add button ad sub view of uitext field ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, dropdown

I have two button namely `programs` and `data`.This two button have drop down option.But when i select the first drop down option for `program` and if i select any data from drop down .say like i select "super" from drop down .Then that super word are selecting in my both button.

With out selecting my second button drop down option.Its automatically changing.For clearly, if i select `super` data from drop down for `program` button,That word "super" is updating in my both drop down button.

Please help me to fix this problem :

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class UserDetailsController: UIViewController {

    var addString: String!

      let dropDown = DropDown()




    @IBOutlet weak var programBtn: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet weak var dataBtn: UIButton!


        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dropdownmethod()


    }




    func dropdownmethod () {


        dropDown.dataSource = [
            "Car",
            "Motorcycle",
            "Van",
            "Truck",
            "Bus",
            "Bicycle",
            "Feet",
            "add"
        ]

        dropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index, item) in
            self.SpectifBtn.setTitle(item, forState: .Normal)
              self.organBtn.setTitle(item, forState: .Normal)

            if item == "add" {

                if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Duplicate file", message: "Afile with the same name already exists.", preferredStyle:
                        UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(self.configurationTextField)

                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
                        print("User click Ok button")
                        print(self.textField.text)
                        self.addString = self.textField.text
                        self.dropDown.dataSource =  [   "Car",
                            "Motorcycle",
                            "Van",
                            "Truck",
                            "Bus",
                            "Bicycle",
                            "Feet", "\(self.addString)", "add"]
                        self.SpectifBtn.setTitle(self.addString, forState: .Normal)
                         self.organBtn.setTitle(self.addString, forState: .Normal)


                    }))

                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: {
                        print("completion block")
                    })

                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
        }

        dropDown.cancelAction = { [unowned self] in
            self.dropDown.selectRowAtIndex(0)
            self.SpectifBtn.setTitle("Canceled", forState: .Normal)
             self.organBtn.setTitle("Canceled", forState: .Normal)
        }

        dropDown.anchorView = SpectifBtn
        dropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y:SpectifBtn.bounds.height)
        dropDown.dismissMode = .Automatic

        dropDown.selectRowAtIndex(3)

    }




    func configurationTextField(textField: UITextField!)
    {
        if let aTextField = textField {
            textField.text = "Filename"
            self.textField = aTextField

        }
    }

    @IBAction func programBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {


        if dropDown.hidden {
            dropDown.show()
        } else {
            dropDown.hide()
        }
    }


    @IBAction func dataBtnPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        if dropDown.hidden {
            dropDown.show()
        } else {
            dropDown.hide()
        }


    }





}
```

My screen shot.When i select any option from my `program` drop down.That option name is automatically updating in my `data` button name also

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: why you are setting title of 2 buttons every time from the dropdown selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dropdown selection of some item, you should check from what  button it comes(by tag for example), now it seems you just select them both here:

self.SpectifBtn.setTitle(item, forState: .Normal)               self.organBtn.setTitle(item, forState: .Normal)